# Connecting arduino to power another device

Tags: arduino, power, batteries, voltage

I have an arduino board which I want to use to give power to a device which uses two 1.5V batteries. I think I have to remove the batteries from the device and control the power supply via arduino, but since I have never did this, I'm asking which is the best way to do this.

How would you use arduino to give power to an external, battery powered device?

*** Adding details ***

I want to power an electro thermoregulator of my house. I have the arduino controlled with a GPRS module, and everything is working fine. The only point left is how to use the arduino to give power to that device.

Comment: Agree with Steven.. need more deeets! Anything can be done but there are good and bad ways.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's battery powered exact voltage is maybe not so important, and you *may* be able to power it from a 3.3 V supply. Let us know what the device is and we can further advise you.

Anyway, I mention the 3.3 V because the Arduino has a 3.3 V regulator on-board, though it can only supply limited power: a current of 50 mA maximum (Uno). Since you talk about batteries this *may* be sufficient, but if you need more power I would bypass the Arduino's voltage regulators altogether, and go directly from the Arduino's power *input* to the 3 V. At high currents and possibly high input voltage a **linear regulator** will lose much power, so that a **switching regulator** may be more fit.

So again, tell us what you want to power and we'll tell you more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't see any specification on my device about the current it uses. It just uses LR6 batteries, so I think 50mA are enough (maybe too much). How do you connect the arduino to the battery holder?